# Cell width control in a table using tabularx environment

Tags: tables, tabularx

[image]

The MWE generates the table, however, I'm intended to do following
1) I tried to add text in 3rd and 4th column but if add more text in 3rd column it also increases the size of cells in the 2nd column, can someone guide me how to encounter the problem. For the sake of understanding, I also share an example formate that what I'm writing to do. Please find below. 
[image]

```
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{A  model}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{12mm}|>{\hsize=0.9\hsize}X|
                                      >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X|
                                      >{\hsize=0.9\hsize}X|}
    \hline
\thead{Ref. no(s)}  & \thead{Used} & \thead{adjective} &   \thead{yield} \\
    \hline
\cite{9}            
                    &Reduces the required computational cost 

                        & \multirow{5}{=}{This pricing scheme refers to a list of price plans for different products or services, which come along with differentiated
quantities or qualities [17]. It can ensure that the pricing entity
(LSE in this paper) can lead the formulation of price, while
providing consumers with more flexible price plans. As shown
in Fig. 2, the main procedure includes:
1) LSE notifies the required load adjustment signals.
2) The i-th CL voluntarily provides information at time t
including price bids (price asked for) θ+
di,t
, θ−
di,t
, upper bounds
of load adjustment P¯ +
di,t
, P¯ −
di,t and elasticity coefficient εdi.
Here + denotes load increase, − denotes load decrease. The
load adjustment at time t is related to not only the price at
time t, but also the price at other times [18]. The elasticity coefficient εdi is a vector including the self-elasticity and
cross-elasticity, i.e.,}  &Research and development in flywheel, compressed air, thermal (molten salts), and hydrogen storage systems are making great progress. In addition to physical storage devices, great potential lies in the exploitation of end-use side energy storage for the grid. For example, energy-demand management of water heaters and air-conditioning cycling utilizes the thermal energy stored in water tanks and buildings at consumer premises in exchange for electricity. Smart vehicle charging and discharging (or vehicle-to-grid, V2G) technology utilizes electrochemical energy stored in the batteries of EVs/PHEVs to act as energy storage for the grid. These “virtual energy-storage systems,” when properly managed in the future grid, can provide a large quantity of cost-efficient power in both directions to the grid.   \\
 \cline{1-2}
\cite{03}           & Minimizes the computational cost and time period
                         &   &   \\
\cline{1-2}
 \cite{14,15}       & Achieving least value to scale up the solution
                        &   &   \\
\hline
Designed model      &  In this paper, a relatively new yet superior clustering algorithm based on density peak, proposed by Rodriguez and Laio,
is introduced and employed & \multirow{5}{=}{According to the clustering features of the CLs’ historical information, LSE can divide CLs into K+ types of load
increase and K− types of load decrease. Moreover, when the
market for DR participants is immature, not all of consumers
will bid voluntarily. In that case, LSE has to forecast the cost
function of load adjustment of consumers based on the historical data. Alternatively, the cost function could be reflected
by other market signals such as reserve service (or frequency
regulation) prices or value of customer reliability.
3)}  &  From Smart Grid to Internet of Energy covers novel and emerging metering and monitoring technologies, communication systems, and technologies in smart grid areas to present a valuable reference for readers from various engineering backgrounds. Considering relevant topics on the essentials of smart grids and emerging wireless communication systems, such as IEEE 802.15.4 based novel technologies, cognitive radio networks and Internet of Energy, this book offers a discussion on the emerging trends and research direction for communication technologies. The book includes research concepts and visualization of smart grids and related communication technologies, making it a useful book for practicing network engineers. \\   \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable, by ading the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Comment: Regarding: " I tried to add text in 3rd and 4th column but if add more text in 3rd column it also increases the size of cells in the 2nd column,":  What would you expect instead?  Do you want to evenly distribute the additional height among the rows in the first/second column? Do you want to change teh column widths (increase thrid, decrease second)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there was no MWE given, I had to guess the documenclass and packages:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} %% guesed because no MWE was given
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{geometry} %% guesed because no MWE was given
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{A  model}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{12mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.75cm}|X|X|}
    \hline
{Ref. no(s)}  & \thead{Used} & \thead{adjective} &   \thead{yield} \\
    \hline
\cite{9}            
                    &Reduces the required computational cost \newline \newline 

                        & \multirow{20}{=}{This pricing scheme refers to a list of price plans for different products or services, which come along with differentiated
quantities or qualities [17]. It can ensure that the pricing entity
(LSE in this paper) can lead the formulation of price, while
providing consumers with more flexible price plans. As shown
in Fig. 2, the main procedure includes:
1) LSE notifies the required load adjustment signals.
2) The i-th CL voluntarily provides information at time t
including price bids (price asked for) θ+
di,t
, θ−
di,t
, upper bounds
of load adjustment P¯ +
di,t
, P¯ −
di,t and elasticity coefficient εdi.
Here + denotes load increase, − denotes load decrease. The
load adjustment at time t is related to not only the price at
time t, but also the price at other times [18]. The elasticity coefficient εdi is a vector including the self-elasticity and
cross-elasticity, i.e.,}  & \multirow{17}{=}{Research and development in flywheel, compressed air, thermal (molten salts), and hydrogen storage systems are making great progress. In addition to physical storage devices, great potential lies in the exploitation of end-use side energy storage for the grid. For example, energy-demand management of water heaters and air-conditioning cycling utilizes the thermal energy stored in water tanks and buildings at consumer premises in exchange for electricity. Smart vehicle charging and discharging (or vehicle-to-grid, V2G) technology utilizes electrochemical energy stored in the batteries of EVs/PHEVs to act as energy storage for the grid. These “virtual energy-storage systems,” when properly managed in the future grid, can provide a large quantity of cost-efficient power in both directions to the grid.}   \\
 \cline{1-2}
\cite{03}           & Minimizes the computational cost and time period \newline \newline
                         &   &   \\
\cline{1-2}
 \cite{14,15}       & Achieving least value to scale up the solution \newline \newline 
                        &   &   \\
\hline
Designed model      &  In this paper, a relatively new yet superior clustering algorithm based on density peak, proposed by Rodriguez and Laio,
is introduced and employed & \multirow{5}{=}{According to the clustering features of the CLs’ historical information, LSE can divide CLs into K+ types of load
increase and K− types of load decrease. Moreover, when the
market for DR participants is immature, not all of consumers
will bid voluntarily. In that case, LSE has to forecast the cost
function of load adjustment of consumers based on the historical data. Alternatively, the cost function could be reflected
by other market signals such as reserve service (or frequency
regulation) prices or value of customer reliability.
3)}  &  From Smart Grid to Internet of Energy covers novel and emerging metering and monitoring technologies, communication systems, and technologies in smart grid areas to present a valuable reference for readers from various engineering backgrounds. Considering relevant topics on the essentials of smart grids and emerging wireless communication systems, such as IEEE 802.15.4 based novel technologies, cognitive radio networks and Internet of Energy, this book offers a discussion on the emerging trends and research direction for communication technologies. The book includes research concepts and visualization of smart grids and related communication technologies, making it a useful book for practicing network engineers. \\   \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As supplement to @Leandriis answer (+1) with (very) small variation in text formatting (using `microtype`, `enumitem` and `caption` packages, removed `multirow` in the last row, etc) and conversion code to form compilable with `pdfLaTeX` engine:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\footnotesize}
\usepackage{microtype}        % new
\usepackage{enumitem}         % new
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}% new

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{A  model}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{12mm}|>{\raggedright}p{16mm}|X|X|}
    \hline
\thead{Ref.\\ no(s)}  & \thead{Used} & \thead{adjective} &   \thead{yield} \\
    \hline
\cite{9}
    &   Reduces the required computational cost 
        &   \multirow{22}{=}{This pricing scheme refers to a list of price plans for different products or services, which come along with differentiated quantities or qualities \cite{17}. It can ensure that the pricing entity (LSE in this paper) can lead the formulation of price, while providing consumers with more flexible price plans. As shown in Fig. 2, the main procedure includes:
                \begin{enumerate}[nosep, leftmargin=*, label=\bfseries\arabic*.]
            \item   LSE notifies the required load adjustment signals.
            \item   The $i$-th CL voluntarily provides information at time $t$ price bids (price asked for)
            $\theta+\frac{di}{dt}, \theta-\frac{di}{dt}$,
                bounds of load adjustment
                $\bar{P}+\frac{di}{dt},\bar{P}-\frac{di}{dt}$
                and elasticity coefficient $\varepsilon di$.
                \end{enumerate}
            Here $+$ denotes load increase, $-$ denotes load decrease. The load adjustment at time $t$ is related to not only the price at time $t$, but also the price at other times \cite{18}. The elasticity coefficient $\varepsilon di$ is a vector including the self-elasticity and cross-elasticity, i.e., \dots}
                &      \multirow{20}{=}{Research and development in flywheel, compressed air, thermal (molten salts), and hydrogen storage systems are making great progress. In addition to physical storage devices, great potential lies in the exploitation of end-use side energy storage for the grid. For example, energy-demand management of water heaters and air-conditioning cycling utilizes the thermal energy stored in water tanks and buildings at consumer premises in exchange for electricity. Smart vehicle charging and discharging (or vehicle-to-grid, V2G) technology utilizes electrochemical energy stored in the batteries of EVs/PHEVs to act as energy storage for the grid. These ''virtual energy-storage systems,'' when properly managed in the future grid, can provide a large quantity of cost-efficient power in both directions to the grid.}           \\
%    \cline{1-2}
\cite{03}
    &   Minimizes the computational cost and time period
        &   &       \\
%\cline{1-2}
 \cite{14,15}
    &   Achieving least value to scale up the solution 
        \vspace{8\baselineskip} % added vertical space that multirow cell's content 
                                % doesn't protrude into the row below it
        &   &       \\
\hline
Designed model
    &  In this paper, a relatively new yet superior clustering algorithm based on density peak, proposed by Rodriguez and Laio, is introduced and employed
        &   According to the clustering features of the CLs’ historical information, LSE can divide CLs into $K^+$ types of load increase and $K^-$ types of load decrease. Moreover, when the market for DR participants is immature, not all of consumers will bid voluntarily. In that case, LSE has to forecast the cost function of load adjustment of consumers based on the historical data. Alternatively, the cost function could be reflected by other market signals such as reserve service (or frequency regulation) prices or value of customer reliability. \dots 
            &   From Smart Grid to Internet of Energy covers novel and emerging metering and monitoring technologies, communication systems, and technologies in smart grid areas to present a valuable reference for readers from various engineering backgrounds. Considering relevant topics on the essentials of smart grids and emerging wireless communication systems, such as IEEE 802.15.4 based novel technologies, cognitive radio networks and Internet of Energy, this book offers a discussion on the emerging trends and research direction for communication technologies. The book includes research concepts and visualization of smart grids and related communication technologies, making it a useful book for practicing network engineers.   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried a way that "work around" the problem. It's not a final solution... we need a answer of someone if more knowledge on this cases.

Particularly, I had a lot of problems with using `table` and `figure` environments. Every time I need some of this elements, I use `minipage` if necessary and one of those packages to take care about figure, table counting and "list of": [`caption`](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) or [`capt-of`](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/capt-of/capt-of.pdf) if I'm not using `memoir` class. If [`memoir`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf) is the class used, it have it own commands to do this (like `\newfixedcaption`, page 195 of memoir documentation).

So, to get this output I use `caption` and `changepage` (to use `adjustwidth` environment in order to centralize the `tabularx`). Other modification was at `\hline`. I don't know why it are too short when I changed the lenghts. But, using `\cline{1-4}` (4 in this case because the total columns), it works.

Other change was at type of column. I create a `newtypecolumn` named `H`, it's a `p` type.

It was necessary change the text... here I had char problems to compile. So, I created a "lorem ipsum" text to try. Now, try with this code and your text.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{caption} %to use \captionof
\usepackage{changepage} %to use adjustwidth

\newcolumntype{H}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{A  model}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5cm}{}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{15mm}|H{3cm}|H{6cm}|H{6cm}|}
\cline{1-4}
\thead{Ref. no(s)}  & \thead{Used} & \thead{adjective} &   \thead{yield} \\
\cline{1-4}
\cite{9}            
                    &Reduces the required computational cost 

                        & \multirow{5}{=}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc.}  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.   \\
\cline{1-2}
\cite{03}           & Minimizes the computational cost and time period
                         &   &   \\
\cline{1-2}
\cite{14,15}       & Achieving least value to scale up the solution
                        &   &   \\
\cline{1-4}
Designed model      &  In this paper, a relatively new yet superior clustering algorithm based on density peak, proposed by Rodriguez and Laio, is introduced and employed & \multirow{5}{=}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc.}  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc.  \\
\cline{1-4}
\end{tabularx}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use `tabularx` if you don't use its `X` type columns? Also, I'd recommend to not use `adjustbox` on a table since it will lead to inconsistent font sizes. `adjustbox` in combination with `tabularx`, which on its own is able to make sure a table steys within the textwidth, is even worse.

Comment: Not me... just follow the code of Shane. And it's just this way I let figures and table in place I want. Everytime I use `figure` or `table` my pdf is a crap. I use `adjustwidth` for 3 years more.

Comment: I definitely have to apologize. Using `adjustwidth` definitely won't cause problems here. I misread it for `adjustbox` which would cause the mentioned problems. However, my question about `tabularx` with no `X` columns stays the same.

Comment: @zarko, leandriis, and Jean. Thank you for your help and sorry for the late reply. All of your answers are appreciated, but I was looking for, as I just edited my question and shared formate of the table (I intented to make). It was my goal to get it. Thanks anyways if you still can help I would be appreciated.